# Importing replacement rules from files

Tags: import, packages

I have some replacement rules written in different files. I am giving an example with two such files.

```bash
cat input1.m 
a1 -> b1
cat input2.m
a2 -> b2
```

Now I have a main file viz. main.m:

```bash
cat main.m
c = a1 + a2;
```

now I want to substitute for `a1` and `a2` at once in the main.m
Desired output will be:

```
c
```

> `b1 + b2`

Here is my attempt, which does not work:

```
c = a1 + a2;
int1 = Import["input1.m"];
int2 = Import["input2.m"];
c = c //. {int1, int2}
```

Comment: Is there any reason in particular that you want to work with individual files?

Comment: yes. The actual problem I am working on consists of many such files containing the substitutions. The expressions for b1,b2 etc are very large. So there is easy solution to my problem, but I want to keep my main.m as clean as possible, not writing many substitutions in the main.m but call them  as a single substitution for all .

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I made a version of what you describe on my system and it worked fine. Try executing you code without the semicolons so you see the values of `int1` and `int2`. Maybe that will shed some light on your problem.

Comment: with the current attempt I am getting like this
{a2 +b1, a1 + b2}

Comment: int1 and int2 show as {a1 -> b1} and {a2 -> b2}

Comment: okay I see the problem ... its because in the input1.m files the substitutions are written within braces ... If I remove the braces its fine!!

Comment: Try `c /. Join[int1, int2]`. You don't need `ReplaceRepeated (//.)`, `ReplaceAll (/.)` will do.